# Depending on godror from Bazel builds with rules_go and CGO to access Oracle from your app or service

Tags: go, bazel, cgo

<sub>This is a question for which I found the answer. I'm adding it to SO as it might be useful for others. If there is a better reply I'll be glad to accept it!</sub>

I'm building some Go services that need to talk to Oracle, using Bazel as the build system in conjunction with the official `rules_go`. The best library for this seems to be [godror](https://github.com/godror/godror/), but when attempting to depend on it, the build fails with:

```
external/com_github_godror_godror/conn.go:10:10: fatal error: 'dpiImpl.h' file not found
#include "dpiImpl.h"
```

This [seems to be due](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/257) to the fact that `gazelle` does not replicate all the magic/implicit things CGO does out of the box when invoked via `go build`, and I'm left to wonder if/how there is a way to properly build that library with Bazel.

As there does not seem to be a proper standalone Go client for Oracle, the only way forward is to get this to work with CGO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing around with the generated `BUILD.bazel` file, I found a workaround that seems to be working at least superficially[1][2]. It involves adding C sources and headers from a subdirectory, as well as patching a C file.

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Shastick/2dde526d39a9c7a822e5565f2d8752a3) for details.

Note that not patching the C file (and including the relevant `dpi.c` file in the `go_library` definition) will cause the build to fail with things along:

```
duplicate symbol '_dpiVar_getReturnedData' in:
    /var/folders/8y/pztgykk94_q4j7fnmjhnbnw0001t4q/T/rules_go_work-940074786/_x3.o
    /var/folders/8y/pztgykk94_q4j7fnmjhnbnw0001t4q/T/rules_go_work-940074786/_x43.o
ld: 1164 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Here I guess some of the CGO magic that happens via `go build` needs to be replaced by the proper flags, but at least things work with the substitution.

For the record, the exploration was mostly done on OS X while things were tested using binaries built on a Linux box.

For anyone interested in the godror specifics here is the [relevant issue](https://github.com/godror/godror/issues/157).

[1]: As in *works for basic queries* and not yet *Tried out every functionality in a production setting*, so YMMV.

[2]: Oddly enough, the workaround makes it impossible to `go install` the sources. If a C/CGO expert has a clue I'd be curious to understand why – oh, by the way, I'm a total C/CGO newbie, so sorry if the problem is obvious.